# Swift 5 pop all Controllers before tab switch

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have trouble pop all controllers when i do click on tabor item. I have tabbar Controller created programmatically. What i tried to do is... user next methods:

```
extension TabbarViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate{

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    })
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    return true
}
}
```

AppDelegate Contains

```
 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let rootNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabbarViewController())
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootNavController
```

Comment: Is your tab bar controller embedded in a navigation controller or do you have multiple navigation controllers as the view controllers for the tab bar controller? Can you show your storyboard?

Comment: i do not use storyboard, i can show my tabbar Controller Class...

Comment: I see. `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)` is popping off the tab bar controller. You should use `viewController as? UINavigationController` instead of `self.navigationController`.

Comment: @Sweeper can you write is as complete answer please?

Comment: yep, it really works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, your tab bar controller is the root of a navigation controller, so `self.navigationController` will refer to *that* navigation controller. This means that the line:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

will try pop the tab bar controller from the navigation controller, but because it is the root, it does nothing.

I assume you have navigation controllers as each of the tabs of the tab bar controller, and you want to pop *those* navigation controllers to their roots, right?

You should use the `viewController` parameter to refer to your desired navigation controllers:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        (viewController as? UINavigationController)?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    })
}
```